# How to initialize WELL512 pseudorandom number generator?

Tags: random, random-seed

I have a WELL512a pseudorandom number generator implementation, but don't know really what is the proper way to initialize it.

The generator has an array of 16 unsigned integers as its state that should be populated. I could use current timestamp, but how? As first entry in the mentioned state array or maybe timestamp should be broken into bits somehow?

I've got code from here: http://lomont.org/Math/Papers/2008/Lomont_PRNG_2008.pdf

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Comment: Seed the entire array using a lesser RNG (like C's rand, after calling srand or course)

Comment: @leppie I don't have any documentation, I've rewritten code from somewhere some time ago, but couldn't find any info about this.

Comment: @ooga Good idea, but I'm writting this in JavaScript and there is no such thing as initializing the built-in generator. That's why I'm trying out WELL512.

Comment: In that case the built-in generator is automatically initialized (when the javascript engine starts). So just use the built-in generator to fill the array. Remember to chop the values off at 16 bits ( % 0x10000 )

Comment: Using/writing code you have no understanding over is never a good idea. Somewhere there must be some theory to use it or make it work as intended.

Comment: @ooga Yes, I could do that, but in some cases I need to generate same number patterns from given predefined seeds.